# Using InheritDownBefore looks like the same as InheritBefore at RewriteOptions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a tree of directories like /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd and inside each directory I have a .htaccess file.

Just today I discovered, that by default, if I use "RewriteEngine On" ONLY THE RULES of the last .htaccess file (at /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/.htaccess) will be executed and all the other .htaccess rules related to mod_rewrite will be completely ignored.

So the user @anubhava told me to use "RewriteOptions InheritBefore" and it worked perfectly, I mean, all the .htaccess rules in all the .htacces files are now being interpreted in order from the parent most to the child most.

My question is this: in this link http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions it's said that InheritDownBefore will apply to all the "**child's**" and InheritBefore will apply to the the "**child**"

But I just did a test, I inserted the line of code below...

```
RewriteOptions InheritBefore
```

... in only the top most parent and it still works as if I had used:

```
RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore
```

So, what is the difference of using those 2 configuration if both to the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference is this:

- `InheritDownBefore` is used in parent's .htaccess so it will go in `/aaa/.htaccess`
- `InheritBefore` is used in child's .htaccess so it will go in `/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/.htaccess` and `/aaa/bbb/ccc/.htaccess` etc.

Effect of both the options will be same i.e.

Rules from the **parent scope** are applied **before** rules specified in the **child scope**.

---

**Update:**

Upon further testing I have found that any of these `RewriteOptions` in parent `.htaccess` is causing same behavior i.e. parent directives become available in child scope though as per documentation 1st and 2nd options are applicable in child .htaccess only.

```
RewriteOptions Inherit
RewriteOptions InheritBefore
RewriteOptions InheritDown
RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore
```

Comment: @InheritBefore thanks man, I did some tests here and if I use InheritBefore in the parent most I dont need to set it inside the children's htaccess! This is weird cause InheritBefore should only work if setted inside children htaccess, but no, if setted in the parent most htaccess it will affect all the children (the same that would happen if I had used InheritDownBefore ).

Comment: Interestingly all these options in parent .htaccess behave same for me: `RewriteOptions Inherit` OR `RewriteOptions InheritDown` OR `RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore` OR `RewriteOptions InheritBefore`

Comment: yeap, good to know you tested those other options too... I have no idea why the same behaviour cause the docs say it very clear about the effect of each option.

Comment: Yes that appears to be a bug in Apache. I have updated answer with all these tests.btw that was a good catch by you

Comment: Thanks a lot @anubhava!